# How do I get the length of an object?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to do it, but it's not working, my object has 2 elements, and it returns 1 element only :/

Here's the code I have

```
var jumbo = document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron");
var button = document.getElementById("changebg");

var tiles = {
  tile1 : {
    header : "header1",
    desc : "desc1"
  },
  tile2 : {
    header : "header2",
    desc : "desc2"
  }
};

function getObjectLength(obj){
  var count = 0;
  for ( var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      count++;
    };
  };
  return count;
};

function changeBackground(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron")[0].innerHTML = getObjectLength(document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron"));
};
```

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).length`

Comment: did you try `Object.keys(obj).length`

Comment: If you are trying to get the number of properties in your `tiles` object, note that the code shown doesn't pass that object to `getObjectLength()`. If you just want to know how many elements have the class `jumbotron` you can say `document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron").length`, because `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a list that has a `.length` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.keys(obj).length` to get the length of Object

```js
    var tiles = {
      tile1 : {
        header : "header1",
        desc : "desc1"
      },
      tile2 : {
        header : "header2",
        desc : "desc2"
      }
    };
    
    console.log(Object.keys(tiles ).length);
```

Your function "getObjectLength" also works and returns 2

```js
var tiles = {
  tile1 : {
    header : "header1",
    desc : "desc1"
  },
  tile2 : {
    header : "header2",
    desc : "desc2"
  }
};

function getObjectLength(obj){
  var count = 0;
  for ( var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      count++;
    };
  };
  return count;
};


console.log(getObjectLength(tiles));
```

I am guessing, you are getting count 1 because there is only one element with the class name "jumbotron".

`getObjectLength(document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try `Object.keys(obj).length` method

```
var tiles = {
 tile1 : {
   header : "header1",
   desc : "desc1"
 },
 tile2 : {
   header : "header2",
   desc : "desc2"
 }
}

console.log(Object.keys(tiles).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron").length;
```

try this.
your function is looking for json object length.